# How to clear screen use Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse

How to use system clear screen in Eclipse IDE. I use Visual Studio 2017 with command system("cls").

I tried system("clear") but cannot.

system("cls") or system("clear");

'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: so i want to clear screen on console of Eclipse, what should i do? I use windows 10, 64bit and 
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

Answer (score 0):

`system()` calls another executable which is provided by your current operating system or a command that's recognized by your default (terminal) shell.

It has nothing to do with your IDE.

There's no generally portable way to *clear the screen* using c++.
The closest portable way you can get is using something like [*ncurses*](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).